# Geospatial clustering with a small sample size

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I just have a very small sample size, containing those 16 coordinates:

```
x <- c(13.41667,13.31070,13.58806,13.31070,13.18361,
       13.19694,13.27821,13.25917,13.62833,13.31056,
       13.30170,13.30880,13.40210,13.41010,13.53250,
       13.06220)

y <- c(52.47944,52.45768,52.54944,52.45768,52.43417,
       52.50778,52.50499,52.57444,52.44444,52.45750,
       52.45370,52.56440,52.46750,52.52050,52.38220,
       52.38130)
```

I tried to cluster them with `kmeans` first, but I think that a circle oriented clustering is not what I am looking for. I was looking forward to find a possibility to cluster the points with a minimum of 2 Points per cluster, that means regarding their density

```
z <- cbind(x,y)
res <- dbscan(z, eps=0.05, minPts = 2)
hullplot(z,res)
```

[image: DBSCAN Cluster Plot of z with eps=.05 and minPt=2]

But this way results in a clustering with many points outside the area. Do you guys have any other ideas how to cluster spatial data with a small sample size like this?

Comment: Hierarchical clustering is often the best choice for small data. Don't cut the tree at a height, but manually identify branches that you deem to be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try relaxing the `eps` parameter.

```
kNNdistplot(z, k = 2)

## Looks like the 'knee' is at eps = 0.08ish rather than 0.05

abline(h=.08, col = "red", lty=2)
```

[image]

Then,

```
res <- z %>% dbscan(., eps = 0.08, MinPts = 2)
hullplot(z, res)
```

[image]